# Selecting all objects inside a mesh

Tags: selection-tools

Is there a quick way to select all objects inside a mesh? For example, I have a 15x15x5 grid of cubes. How would I automatically select all the cubes that are inside the toroid-like mesh object?

[image]

Update:

Weight Mode:

[image]

Torus Settings:

[image]

Comment: What will happen with objects partialy in-out?

Comment: @vklidu Good question. I would prefer if they were selected, but that's not very important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since script is not here so one handmade tech. using **Dynamic Paint** from Physics Properties. Tested with official 2.82

[image]

- for Torus add Dynamic Paint as **Brush**
- Join Cubes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, add Dynamic Paint as **Canvas** > *Surface Type* > *Weight* and in *Output* click "+" icon if "dp_weight" is marked red. When you switch to *Weight Paint* mode you can see all Cubes placed inside Torus are red.
- Apply modifier for Cubes

[image]

When you switch to Edit mode you can see weight color as well if you enable Viewport Overlays > Vertex Group Weight.

- To select red cubes go to Properties Editor > Object Data > Vertex Group > Select
- Because some of the cubes were selected only partialy, you can select whole these by Select Linked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

[image]

Notes: If you need Cubes separated back, just press <kbd>P</kbd> > by Loose parts.

(In experimental 2.83 I have some glitches in 3Dview editor > Weight Paint mode, but weight is visible from XYZ axis.Probably some personal issue with graphics card, because on Eevee mode Blender crash totaly.)

Just for fun ...
[image]

[image]

Comment: Damn! It's answers like this, where I realize, that I'm just scratching the surface in Blender... :). Thanks for such an elegant solution.

Comment: @vklidu Thanks again for your idea for helping with all the related questions!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you scene or objects are structured as you can select by Parent, Color, etc.

One of the easiest ways is to put all the smaller cubes into a collection (or collections of collections) and then selection is easy by right clicking on the collection and click Select Objects *or* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>G</kbd> -> Collection.

[image]

Another way I have used is to select by material. That is, assign the same material to all your similar objects and then select by Material:  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>L</kbd> -> Material.

All of this takes a little bit to set up, but once done, selection is easy.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. My question is specifically about selecting all object _inside_ a larger mesh.

Comment: Unless you object has similar properties that can be selected by Groups `Shift + G` or Linked `Shift + L` or naming pattern `Select-> Select Pattern` then I don't think there is an automated way. I think you may have to manually do so, then put them all in a collection.

Comment: I wonder if there's an add-on for that.

Answer (score -3):

I would press A  and then shift+ click to deselect one