# How to select vertices contained in object

Tags: edit-mode, animation-nodes, sverchok

How can vertices be selected if they are contained in another?
Is there a way to do this using manual editing, Animation Nodes, or Sverchok?

Example:
[image]

How can the vertices contained within the cylinder be selected?

This is a similar question - [Selecting all objects inside a mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166632/selecting-all-objects-inside-a-mesh) , in this case the question applies to vertices.

Comment: See this question for your answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166632/selecting-all-objects-inside-a-mesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you can:

Select the cylinder, shift select the grid then enter edit mode.

Go to wireframe view and uncheck X Ray. Then from the top view, box select.

[image]

Comment: ... and invert. Why have I never thought of this?

Comment: @RobinBetts, please do not use comments to ask question, prefer the question part instead.

Answer (score 1):

http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverch/html/nodes/analyzer/points_inside_mesh.html
here you can make so
http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverch/html/nodes/solid/points_inside_solid.html
or here